# Keras: logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,4] labels_size=[32,2]

Tags: python, keras, image-classification

I am trying to trin an image classifier with Keras and i keep getting the error:

> InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable:
> logits_size=[32,4] labels_size=[32,2]      [[node
> categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at
> :2) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_10520]
>
> Function call stack: train_function

I am creating my Model like this:

```
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
data_folder = os.path.join("data", "train_min")
test_folder = os.path.join("data", "test_min")

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(data_folder,
                                             target_size = (224, 224),
                                             batch_size = 32,
                                             class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_folder,
                                        target_size = (224, 224),
                                        batch_size = 32,
                                        class_mode = 'categorical')
```

After creating the training_set and the test_set i get the message

> Found 3520 images belonging to 2 classes. (training_set)

> Found 480 images belonging to 2 classes. (test_set)

So loading images works fine, i guess.

---

---

But when i try to execute this code:

```
model.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 5,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 200)
```

I am getting the error i already showed you above:

> InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable:
> logits_size=[32,4] labels_size=[32,2]      [[node
> categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at
> :2) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_10520]
>
> Function call stack: train_function

How do i change the label size? Isn't Labeling done automatically when i create the training_set? What are logits?

Comment: Your last layer should match the number of category you have

Answer (score 2):

try change 4 to 2 in line:
predictions = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

Comment: This is the direct answer to fix their bug.  In the bigger picture, it looks like their task is binary classification.  They should set the units in the final Dense to 1 with a sigmoid activation, set the class mode in the `flow_from_directory` to "binary" and use binary_crossentropy as the loss function.